# Raspberry pi 3 location in a set field, no gps

Tags: wireless

I'm developing a project which involves a raspberry pi 3 remote control rover and I need to know the exact location of the raspberry pi rover in a set field.

Let's say I have four logs, one in each corner of the square field (the goal right now is to extend this to any shape field, any number of corners), every of them equipped with (some kind of wave technology) that allows me to triangulate the position (based on signal intensity) of the raspberry pi rover.

The distance between logs should not be bigger than 30m (~100feet) and there is no line of sight guaranted.

The question is: Which kind of technology should I use, infrared, wifi, bluetooth, radio, ultrasound, etc? or, is there any better approach to this problem?

Comment: Does the field have a known layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infrared and ultrasound are blocked by obstacles. Since you cannot guarantee a line-of-sight, eliminate these two. WiFi, Bluetooth and radio (RF) will have the range you need and should be able to penetrate obstacles you are likely to have, then you would use their relative signal strength (RSSI) to do your triangulation calculation.